# Java implement class in interface

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

Say I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Crop {
}

public abstract class Fruit extends Crop {
}

public interface Edible /* ALWAYS IMPLEMENTED BY A CROP */ {
}

public class Apple extends Fruit implements Edible /* BOTH A CROP AND EDIBLE */ {
}

public class Holly extends Fruit /* NOT EDIBLE */ {
}

public class Wheat extends Crop implements Edible {
}
```

Now, I want to make sure that every `Edible` (interface) is a `Crop` (class).

Why can I not say:

```
public interface Edible implements Crop {
}
```

So that `Edible` itself can only be implemented by classes that extend `Crop`?

Is there a workaround for this, especially when passing `Edible` as a generic parameter that requires a `Crop`?

Comment: Because an `interface` `extend` from other `interface`s ;). Classes `implement` `interface`s

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer! I do not want to extend my interface from another interface, but from a class. In this example Edible should [extend or implement] Crop, so that it itself can only be implemented by classes that extend Crop. (and potentially use Crop-methods).

Comment: You should write `public abstract class Crop implements Edible`, the reverse is not possible (and wouldn't make sense in a logical sense). If you only want subclasses of `Crop` to extend `Edible`, you should probably use sealed classes (Java 17 or higher).

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel! There are crops (in this case Holly), which are not Edible, but everything that is Edible is a Crop. So basically, the interface Edible should only be implemented by classes that extend Crop, for example Apple and Wheat, but not all classes should implement it.

Comment: `public interface Edible implements Crop` should be `public interface Edible extends Crop`

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer! I tried it out, but it tells me that an interface (Edible) cannot extend a class (Crop): "interface expected here"

Comment: If every Edible is a Crop then you should remove Edible and put any of its methods inside Crop.

Comment: @Michael thanks that technically works, but I would have methods (for example getHealthiness()) that just don't apply for any other crops, because they cannot even be eaten (at least by humen). I could throw an exception if such a method is called from a non-edible crop, but it would be dirty and mean, that I could not for example restrict a method to only accept Edibles as a parameter and not any Crop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implement a Java Class on an Interface. Interfaces can only `extend` other interfaces. So, in that way, you can declare another interface (and implement it on `Crop`). Then, you can extend this new interface on `Editable`.

This can be something like:

```
public abstract class Crop implements NewInterface{
}

public interface Edible extends NewInterface {
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice approach! I will need to accept that I cannot use final methods with this approach.

Comment: Be warned though, this doesn't prevent classes other than `Crop` to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

The only option to restrict what classes can implement an interface is using a [sealed interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html) (introduced in Java 17), which restrict what class can inherit it. However, your use-case has the "problem" that not all crops are edible, which complicates matters.

On the face of it, your problem is not solvable, unless you want to explicitly list all possible classes in the interface.

For example, your problem could be solved like

```java
public sealed interface Edible 
        permits Apple, Wheat {
}

public abstract class Crop {
}

public abstract class Fruit extends Crop {
}

public final class Apple extends Fruit implements Edible /* BOTH A CROP AND EDIBLE */{
}

public class Holly extends Fruit /* NOT EDIBLE */ {
}

public final class Wheat extends Crop implements Edible {
}
```

You could relax some of the constraints by using something like:

```java
public sealed interface Edible 
        permits EdibleFruit, Wheat {
}

public abstract class Crop {
}

public abstract class Fruit extends Crop {
}

public non-sealed abstract class EdibleFruit extends Fruit implements Edible {
}

public class Apple extends EdibleFruit /* BOTH A CROP AND EDIBLE */{
}

public class Holly extends Fruit /* NOT EDIBLE */ {
}

public final class Wheat extends Crop implements Edible {
}
```

But that could lead to a complicated hierarchy (e.g. consider that some sub-types of an edible fruit are not edible).

It might make more sense to handle this differently, e.g. a check on edibility or toxicity, or maximum safe dose, or something like that.

Comment: This works, while I cannot use any methods from Crop inside of Edible.  I'll go with the approach @Sergio Quinteiro, but I will use this to permit specific interfaces and Crop itself to implement NewInterface.

Comment: @Cactusroot The need to use methods of `Crop` inside `Edible` was not a constraint mentioned in your question. But yes, using an interface implemented/extended by both `Crop` and `Edible` is then the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Why not constraint `Edible`?

```
interface Edible<T extends Crop> {}
```

so that every edible must instanciate the interface if it subclass `Crop`:

```
class A extends Crop implements Edible<A> {} // Ok
class B implements Edible<B> {} // Bad
```

At least every `Edible` needs to be instantiated with a class that is a `Crop`. But you can do weird things like:

```
class C implements Edible<A> {}
```

Comment: I am using such a structure already for self-generics, it's just that Edible is still not a Crop and thus cannot be used as a generic resolver if it is generic itself.